# Allow resize on "Designed for iPad" App for Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Is there a way to allow an App running in *Design for iPad* mode on an Apple Silicon Mac to be resized? I thought it was enough to choose "Optimize Interface for Mac", but that doesn't work.

Is it a feature that I can enable only compiling the App for Catalyst or Rosetta?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out on my own. If you want to enable the screen resizing, you have to disable "Requires full screen" on the project settings and enable all the orientations. That, unfortunately, let the App on iPad be able to be splitted (1/3, 1/2, 2/3) so you have to adapt the interface.

[image]

I don't think it's possibile to keep these two features separated, but it makes sense because if you want your App to be resizable, you have to do all the interfaces adjustments that you would need as well on the iPad for all the size classes.